# ssh into a server and download data

Tags: ssh, tar

So I've been using this command

```
tar zcf - * | ssh root@ip "tar xzf - -C home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2"
```

to upload stuff to other servers. However I have to be in the ssh of the server that needs to download things. So I tried to reverse the command like this

```
ssh root@ip "tar xzf - -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4" | tar zcf - *
```

It gives errors

```
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

and idles after I put the command in.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need to do.  What machine do you want to do it from? The local or the remote?

Comment: And if you're going to do `f -`, then you might as well skip that part entirely - the default source and target for `tar` is stdin/stdout.

Comment: I need to ssh from current machine into target machine and download the target directory on the target machine into my current directory in my current ssh/machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command came close:

```
ssh root@ip "tar xzf - -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4" | tar zcf - *
```

But you forgot to switch extraction and creation - now the first command is extracting (from nothing, presumably) and the second command is creation. Try:

```
ssh root@ip "tar zc -C /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4 ." | tar zxv
```

Comment: I think it might actually be working. its idling but on duplicate ssh im seeing hdd usage increase.

Comment: @user2656801 use `zxv` the next time you run this command, so that you can which files have been copied.

Comment: yo it worked. I did use the second command

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're doing this like you are as it seems overly complex since there are specialized tools to do this. Maybe consider using rsync or scp?

```
rsync --progress -rvz root@ip:/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server2 .
```

Used -r for recursive, -z for compression.

Comment: I have tried rsync and it does things very slowly. Different file sizes effect it's speed. rsync does the same task 5 times slower.